# Unable to install (re-install) Toad DB2

Tags: installation, db2, toad

When I try to re-install Toad, i get the following error message:
"The Toad for DB2 installer has detected an existing 64-bit DB2 environment on your computer. This installation of Toad for DB2 includes a 32-bit DB2 client. However, DB2 does not allow both 32-bit and 64bit DB2 Environment to exist on the same computer."

[image]

I am using Windows 7 (64bit) and just uninstalled Toad prior to this installation. (Trying to re-install toad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O and here is the solution. Hope this can help others as well:)
Opened registry, looked for the keys
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IBM
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\IBM
Just renamed the IBM Folder into something else
After that the 64 bit Toad setup will pass the checking for any installed IBM software. And there you go! :)